# jquery draggable - get dragged object position from the droppable object

Tags: jquery, positioning, draggable, droppable

I am dragging an element (draggable) inside another one (droppable), when it drops, it clones the object to the droppable div. But with no position info, so the cloned object is 0 left and 0 top. My code is as follows:

```
$('#objects div').draggable({revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'});
$('#objects').droppable({});
$('.ace').droppable({
    drop:function(e, ui){

        var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        var parent = $('.ace');

        ui.draggable.detach();
        clone.appendTo(parent);

    }               
});
```

I know i should calculate the dragged object position against the container position and set the data into the clone position, but I can`t get the dragged object position from  the droppable method, neither I could clone the object from the draggable method properly.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e.pageX 
e.pageY
```

will have the position information of the dropped element,
do a `console.log(e)` to see what all you can get from the ei object